# Copy only needed folders to destination folder using folderlist in Textfile using batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line

I want to copy only specific folders along with files in it from source location to destination location. Folder list is given in separate 
textfile.

Textfile has values like

```
01
02
03
```

E.g of source folders parent folders and subfolders

```
a --> 

   01 --> Hi.txt
b --> 
   c -- > 
        d --> 
              02  --> foo.txt, abc.xlsx
e --> 
     02 --> foo.txt
f -->
     03 --> cde.txt
g -->
     04 --> xyz.txt
```

Destination folder required output

```
01 --> Hi.txt
02 --> foo.txt, abc.xlsx
02[2] --> foo.txt
03 --> cde.txt
```

My current code which is failing to create duplicate folder with suffix [2] in destination folder and instead asks for [overwrite the files in destination folder which exists already]:

e.g. folder 02 in above example which occurs twice in two different subfolders. using below code it only creates one 02 folder in destination, copies the files from first 02 source folder in it and for the next occurrence , it simply says folder already exists in destination do you want to overwrite the files whose names are similar to files already in destination 02 folder.

Can someone help me resolve this issue and help me create duplicate folder with suffix [2] , [3] .. and so on for any number of occurrence of duplicate folder name.

Code:

```
 @echo off

    set SRC_FOLDER="C:\Source\"
    set DST_FOLDER="C:\Destination"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in 
 (C:\Users\Desktop\CopyScript\TextFile.txt) 
    do (
    for /d /r %SRC_FOLDER% %%G in (*) do (
        set /x counter=0
        REM echo %%~nxG and %%G and %%a
        if "%%~nxG"=="%%a" (

            :loop
            if exist %DST_FOLDER%\%%a[%x%] set /x 
      counter=!counter!+1 && goto :loop
                mkdir %DST_FOLDER%\%%a[%x%]
                xcopy "%%G" %DST_FOLDER%\%%a[%x%]
            )       
     )
     )
```

Comment: There are several wrong line-breaks in the code you posted, and there is no `set /X`; so is it really the code you are using? Please copy it from your script, do not retype it here!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57193198.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*"') DO IF /i "%%~nxe"=="%%a" (
  SET "copied="
  IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%a" XCOPY "%%e\*" "%destdir%\%%a\"&SET "copied=y"
  IF NOT DEFINED copied FOR /L %%s IN (1,1,999) DO IF NOT DEFINED copied IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%a[%%s]" XCOPY "%%e\*" "%destdir%\%%a[%%s]\"&SET "copied=y"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q57193198.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Read each line from the file to `%%a`then use a `dir /s/b` to create a directory list in `%%e`. Match the leaf-name in `%%~nxe` to the name from the file. On matches, set the flag `copied` to *nothing* then if the destination `%%a` directory is missing, use `xcopy` to create it, copy the files and then set `copied` to *something*.

if the first attempt failed (ie. the `%%a` directory existed) then `copied` will be undefined, so detect the presence of `%%a[1..999]` On the first one of these to *not* exist, do the `xcopy` with modified destination-directory, and set the `copied` flag. Once the `copied` flag is set, the `if not exist ..%%a[?]` is gated-out.